# C# initializing date with AddDays

Tags: c#

I'm creating a date like this:

```
DateTime TheDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180);
TheDate = new DateTime(TheDate.Year, TheDate.Month, TheDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Basically, I'm creating a date that's 180 days prior to today and then I'm adjusting this date to be the beginning of that day. Is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: What you're doing is bad anyways, because you're losing the "Kind" of date it is (UTC in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DateTime TheDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180).Date;
```

The Date method returns a DateTime without the timestamp

Comment: Makes no difference but I'd prefer `DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-180);` :)